# Passing "username" value from one component to another component in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, socket.io

I understand how to nest a child-component within a parent-component in Angular 2. That's easy enough to accomplish. But I'm a little unclear as to how to just pass one value down from one component to another. In my use-case I want to pass a username down from a login component, to a chat component - so that the username will display in the chatbox. That's all I need to do. I understand the @Input() decorator is probably something to use here, I'm just unclear as to how to actually pass in the value using it.

This is what I have in my login component html:

```
<div class="center-box">
        <form name="form" class="form-fields" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && login()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !username.valid }">
                <input type="text" form autocomplete="off" class="form-control" name="username" [(ngModel)]="model.username" #username="ngModel" required />
                <div *ngIf="f.submitted && !username.valid" class="help-block">Username is required</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !password.valid }">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" [(ngModel)]="model.password" #password="ngModel" required />
                <div *ngIf="f.submitted && !password.valid" class="help-block">Password is required</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="submit-btn">Login</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div align="center" [ngStyle]="{'color': 'red'}"><alert></alert></div>
    </div>
```

And my login component looks like this:

```
import { AuthenticationService } from './../../data/authentication.service';
import { AlertService } from './../../data/alert.service';
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: 'app/views/login/login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/views/login/login.component.css']
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

    model: any = {};
    loading = false;
    username;
    password;

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
        private alertService: AlertService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        // reset login status
        this.authenticationService.logout();
    }

    login() {
        this.loading = true;
        this.authenticationService.login(this.model.username, this.model.password)
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.router.navigate(['/']);
                    console.log('User logged in as: ' + this.model.username);
                },
                error => {
                    this.alertService.error(error);
                    this.loading = false;
                });
    }
}
```

My chat component html looks like this:

```
<div class="centered-display" align="center">
  <h3>User: {{username}}</h3>
  <div *ngFor="let message of messages" class="message">
    {{username}}: {{message.text}}
  </div>
  <input class="form-group" [(ngModel)]="message" (keypress)="eventHandler($event)">
  <div class="spacing">
    <button class="submit-btn" md-button (click)="sendMessage()">SEND</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's the chat component file:

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ChatService } from './chat.service';
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { TabPage } from '../../ui/tab-navigation/tab-page';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './chat.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chat.component.less']
})
export class ChatComponent extends TabPage implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  username = '';
  messages = [];
  users = [];
  routes;
  connection;
  userbase;
  route;
  message;
  user;

  constructor(private chatService:ChatService, router: Router, route: ActivatedRoute) {

        super(router, route);

        this._title = 'Chat Room';

        this.addEventListener('paramsChange', function(params) {

            this._title = 'Chat Room';

        }.bind(this));
   }

  sendMessage() {
    this.chatService.sendMessage(this.message);
    this.message = '';
  }

  sendUser() {
    this.chatService.sendUser(this.user);
    this.user = '';
  }

    trackUser() {
    this.chatService.trackUser(this.route);
    console.log('A user just navigated to ' + this.route);
  }

  // For when user clicks "enter/return" to send message
  eventHandler(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
        this.chatService.sendMessage(this.message);
        this.message = '';
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.connection = this.chatService.getMessages().subscribe(message => {
      this.messages.push(message);
    });
    this.userbase = this.chatService.getUsers().subscribe(user => {
      this.users.push(user);
    });
    this.routes = this.chatService.getRoutes().subscribe(route => {
      this.routes.push(route);
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.connection.unsubscribe();
    this.userbase.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

So basically it comes down to how I pass the value in where the h3 is in the chat component view:

#### User: {{username}}

. How do I bind the username value from the login-component, and pass it in here in the chat component?

Comment: it's already bound to model.username

Comment: But how do I pass that through to the other component/component view?

Comment: other component will listen the event sent from another component

Comment: Why would it do that without me telling it to? I have to somehow use the @Input decorator to accomplish that.

Comment: because you didn't tell it to do so.

Comment: That's my question. HOW do I tell it to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shared service would probably be best: Make a new service:

```
@Injectable()
export class YourSharedService {
    sharedUser: {
        // your properties here... e.g
        username: 'string'
    };
}
```

and then inject it in your constructor in both parent and child and access it in your components:

```
constructor(private yourSharedService: YourSharedService......) {  }
```

in your login-component you can assign the user to your newly created service, so that you have access to it in all components you inject your shared service:

assign: `this.yourSharedService.sharedUser = yourUserObject`

then you can access the user in your components:

```
localUserObject = this.yourSharedService.sharedUser;
```

Some additional info: The `@Input` works when your childcomponent is not behind a different route. When your childcomponent is in a child route, shared service is the way to go :)

Shared services goes both ways, when you e.g make changes to your user properties in one component and store the user in your shared service, the other components that share that same object (or whatever) get the current info automatically, e.g when you route to another component that has the shared service implemented.

Comment: "The @Input works when your childcomponent is *not behind a different route*."

Ahh, okay. Thanks, very helpful. That's the part I was missing. So shared service is the way to go in these instances. Okay, got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should probably set up a separate user service where you store the user info after login. Then you can inject the user service (make sure to actually make it injectable using the `@Injectable()` decorator) into your chat component (through the constructor: `constructor(public userService: UserService)`) and reference it in your template: `User: {{ userService.username }}`.